# Inserting Image Into BLOB Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, blob

I am trying to insert an image into an BLOB field in a signatures which i will then select from the table and render on a report. I cannot seem to figure how to get the image into the table. I did an insert however when i render only the path to the image was shown on the report and not the image itself.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE esignatures (
  office   NUMBER(6,0)  NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  iblob    BLOB         NOT NULL
)
```

**INSERT Statement (SQL)**

```
INSERT INTO esignatures  
VALUES (100, 'BOB', utl_raw.cast_to_raw('C:\pictures\image1.png'));
```

I know for sure i am inserting the String location in the form of a HEX value how can i get the image HEX value in the table so when i render i will see the image being displayed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot access a local directory from pl/sql.  If you use bfile, you will setup a directory ([create directory](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5007.htm#SQLRF01207)) on the server where Oracle is running where you will need to put your images.

If you want to insert a handful of images from your local machine, you'll need a client side app to do this.  You can write your own, but I typically use Toad for this.  In schema browser, click onto the table.  Click the data tab, and hit + sign to add a row.  Double click the BLOB column, and a wizard opens.  The far left icon will load an image into the blob:

[image]

SQL Developer has a similar feature.  See the "Load" link below:

[image]

If you need to pull images over the wire, you can do it using pl/sql, but its not straight forward.  First, you'll need to setup ACL list access (for security reasons) to allow a user to pull over the wire.  See [this article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-11gr1.php) for more on ACL setup.

Assuming ACL is complete, you'd pull the image like this:

```
declare
    l_url varchar2(4000) := 'http://www.oracleimg.com/us/assets/12_c_navbnr.jpg';
    l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
    l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;
    l_raw RAW(2000);
    l_blob BLOB;
begin
   -- Important: setup ACL access list first!

    DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(l_blob, FALSE);

    l_http_request  := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(l_url);
    l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);

  -- Copy the response into the BLOB.
  BEGIN
    LOOP
      UTL_HTTP.read_raw(l_http_response, l_raw, 2000);
      DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_blob, UTL_RAW.length(l_raw), l_raw);
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body THEN
      UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);
  END;

  insert into my_pics (pic_id, pic) values (102, l_blob);
  commit;

  DBMS_LOB.freetemporary(l_blob); 
end;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this is a really nice piece of information however my database is local. I have a development environment.

Comment: @devdar Download [SQL Developer IDE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) and use it (as I show above).  It comes in handy for all things Oracle ;-)

Comment: The image should be .bmp format. It worked only with a BMP file

Answer (score 10):

You should do something like this:

1) create directory object what would point to server-side accessible folder

```
CREATE DIRECTORY image_files AS '/data/images'
/
```

2) 
Place your file into OS folder directory object points to

3)
Give required access privileges to Oracle schema what will load data from file into table:

```
GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY image_files TO scott
/
```

4) Use BFILENAME, EMPTY_BLOB functions and DBMS_LOB package (example NOT tested - be care) like in below:

```
DECLARE
  l_blob BLOB; 
  v_src_loc  BFILE := BFILENAME('IMAGE_FILES', 'myimage.png');
  v_amount   INTEGER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO esignatures  
  VALUES (100, 'BOB', empty_blob()) RETURN iblob INTO l_blob; 
  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(v_src_loc, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  v_amount := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(v_src_loc);
  DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(l_blob, v_src_loc, v_amount);
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(v_src_loc);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

After this you get the content of your file in BLOB column and can get it back using Java for example.

edit: One letter left missing: it should be LOADFROMFILE.

Comment: +1 Perhaps you should emphasize the point that the OS user that is running the Oracle database (presumably LOCAL SYSTEM in this case) needs to have access to the directory.

Comment: the user running the oracle database is not the same as the database user. However can you tell me where the directory gets created

Comment: I tried this however it does not work CREATE DIRECTORY myData AS 'C:\myData'; GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY images1 TO devdar; the directory does not get created devdar is the OS user. The directory does not get created

Comment: @devdar this solution will create a directory on the server where Oracle is running (not your location machine).  You will need to use a client side app (not pl/sql on server side) to pull directly from a local directory.  If I have time I will show you how to pull images over http and insert using pl/sql