# How to insert a large hex into a BLOB column?

Tags: c, oracle, plsql

I'm building a C program with PL/SQL on it, which creates a QRCODE bmp and saves that file, but i need to send it to a table column of BLOB type, the problem is I don't have access to Oracle server directory so i can't "upload" the file. I have been trying to send the hex via an update query with the function HEXTORAW(oracle function) like this:

```
update test set qrcodeIMG=hextoraw('424df64a010000...');
```

But the hex string is so large that it fails to update and says the string can only have 4000 chars...  The string has 5623 chars, but it obviously can have more acording to the size of the QRCODE generated. Is there any other way i can make this?

Comment: Sigh. Hex is a representation for printing, not a datatype.

Comment: If you can place the file on the net  (lan or wan) where the oracle server can access it, then the last option in the accepted answer of this question would do the trick:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855935/inserting-image-into-blob-oracle-10g

Comment: I can't... Is there a way to build a BLOB object with a pl/sql block by "pieces"?

Comment: Can't you call PL/SQL from C using Bind-Variables and assigning a BLOB directly ?

Comment: Will try this out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is transferring the data from C to the PL function since each parameter is limited in size. If the max size of the image is known you can declare a function/procedure with enough parameters and cut up the data. Unfortunately, the RAW data type is limited to 2000 bytes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_blob(key test.id%type, 
        part1 RAW(2000), 
        part2 RAW(2000), 
        part3 RAW(2000), 
        part4 RAW(2000), 
        part5 RAW(2000)),
        part6 RAW(2000)),
        part7 RAW(2000)),
        part8 RAW(2000)),
        part9 RAW(2000)),
        part10 RAW(2000)) AS
    l_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
    DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(l_blob, FALSE);
    DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_blob, UTL_RAW.length(part1), part1);
    DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_blob, UTL_RAW.length(part2), part2);
    DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_blob, UTL_RAW.length(part3), part3);
    DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_blob, UTL_RAW.length(part4), part4);
    DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_blob, UTL_RAW.length(part5), part5);
    DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_blob, UTL_RAW.length(part6), part6);
    DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_blob, UTL_RAW.length(part7), part7);
    DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_blob, UTL_RAW.length(part8), part8);
    DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_blob, UTL_RAW.length(part9), part9);
    DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_blob, UTL_RAW.length(part10), part10);
    UPDATE test SET qrcodeIMG = l_blob WHERE id = key;
    commit;
   DBMS_LOB.freetemporary(l_blob); 
END;
/
```

Obviously, this is not the way it is meant to be done. If you can, using a file is a better choice.

**EDIT:**

Oracle has [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_16lob.htm#1001868) on how to properly write a LOB from C in the LOB chapter of the Pro*C/C++ Precompiler Programmer's Guide.

Comment: It works as long as the images are small. If you need to be able to handle large blobs this method will be very cumbersome.

Comment: I will pick this up again tomorrow and will give some feedback.

Comment: That examples link was the best solution. Solved all my problems, thank you Klas.