# How to insert a picture into BLOB column in Oracle table using INSERT syntax?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert

I have a simple table where I want to insert an image that exists on my machine.I would like to insert the picture into my table's BLOB column. Just wondering how can I do it. I understand that there are some existing solutions which are related to BLOB but none have helped me directly by using INSERT SYNTAX.

```
CREATE TABLE test(id int,photo BLOB);

INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,'Path of the picture\filename');
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855935/inserting-image-into-blob-oracle-10g

Comment: That didn't help... I already checked that link..

Comment: Whats the problem with simple insert? Your code is ok, except `photo` column value. Insert blob value, not the path.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create a directory to store images and grant read, write permission to the user. Then you can use BFILENAME function to insert the image.

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba

SQL> create directory image_dir as '/home/oracle/Desktop/';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory image_dir to jay;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn jay  
Enter password: 
Connected.
SQL> CREATE TABLE test(id number, image blob);

Table created.
```

Now, to store the give image can use the following insert statement.

```
[oracle@myserver Desktop]$ ls -l | grep abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall   269748 Apr 16 01:23 abc.png


SQL> INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,bfilename('IMAGE_DIR','abc.png'));

1 row created.
```

**Reference:** [BFILENAME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions012.htm#SQLRF00610)