# Inserting blob in oracle DB where I don't have permissions to create tables

Tags: oracle, blob

I was looking at stack overflow for ways to insert blob data in oracle and found some ways to do so ([How to insert a picture into BLOB column in Oracle table using INSERT syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432415/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-blob-column-in-oracle-table-using-insert-syntax)).
I am trying to insert a blob already retrieved in my oracle DB on an environment where I cannot create new tables. How do I insert this blob that I have? Can I do something where I convert the BLOB I have to raw data and then insert?
    Insert into TABLE values (1234,utl_raw.cast_to_raw(blob_data))
Will the data be unmodified? Thanks!

Comment: If you can't create new tables, do you have any existing tables which have blob columns? What type of column are you trying to insert this blob into?

Comment: I am trying to insert this blob in a table that has blob columns.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it sounds like you already have a blob in the database, and you want to insert it into a table. For this example, let's say it's this empty blob.

```
select empty_blob() as my_blob from dual;
```

You don't need to do any conversion; just insert it into your table.

```
insert into MY_TABLE (example_column, blob_column) values 
  (1, (select empty_blob() as my_blob from dual) );
```

If it's PL/SQL, it's even cleaner:

```
declare
  my_blob blob;
begin
  my_blob := empty_blob();
  insert into MY_TABLE (example_column, blob_column) 
    values (1, my_blob );
end;
/
```

If you give us more details about how you're retrieving and storing your blob, or what your table structure looks like, we can probably provide a more specific answer.

Comment: I have the BLOB as a file that I downloaded from a DB and now this file that has the blob, I want to insert in my table.

Comment: So you want to insert a file as a blob into your table?

Comment: Hi, thanks @kfinity for your time! What I did was I converted the blob file to hex data and used Oracle SQL's hextoraw(...) method in the insert statement to insert the data in my DB. Thanks once again!