# How to Insert Blob into a table in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `blobtest` which was created with the following code:

```
create table blobtest(
id number,
file_data blob);
```

I want to insert data representing a file on my computer into this table. How may I do this?

Comment: It's a duplicate question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855935/inserting-image-into-blob-oracle-10g

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting Image Into BLOB Oracle 10g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855935/inserting-image-into-blob-oracle-10g)